# Collected works of David Hilbert?

Tags: reference-request

1) Is there a collected works of D. Hilbert?

2) If 1) is affirmative, is there an English translation of the collected works of D. Hilbert?

Comment: Hilbert's invariant theory papers have been translated by M. Ackerman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Wikipedia Project to make Hilbert's collected works avaioable online: [David Hilbert Gesammelte Abhandlungen Erster Band–Zahlentheorie](https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/David_Hilbert_Gesammelte_Abhandlungen_Erster_Band_%E2%80%93_Zahlentheorie)

It still needs some help!

Comment: It is now complete (at least the number theory part) and available at https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/David_Hilbert_Gesammelte_Abhandlungen_Erster_Band_–_Zahlentheorie

Comment: https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/David_Hilbert_Gesammelte_Abhandlungen_Erster_Band_–_Zahlentheorie

Comment: Somehow it seems not possible to link here the full URL. You have to add _Zahlentheorie at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Hilbert's Collected works (gesammelte abhandlungen) in three volumes (and in German) were published by Chelsea Publishing. I have the first volume on number theory. As far as I can tell, the AMS now offers only volume 1 (http://www.ams.org/bookstore/chelsealist). You can find used copies of the other volumes by searching for "hilbert gesammelte abhandlungen" at online used book stores.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes and its available online.

2) No.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please post the link? For I did not find it online.

Comment: Easiest is to go to libgen and search under "hilbert abhandlung"